# putting Button inside a TextBlock(or maybe something else) to make it work like the one on video?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

with Silverlight 4,

I am trying to create the TextBlock just like the one on the Microsoft LightSwitch(Modal Window Picker) . So I can use it as a customControl inside the GridView columns.

this is the link from youtube: you can see the one i am talking starting at time 08:54 / 14.50

on the Business label

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVApqFMqRbU

Basically, when the mouse moves over to the Business textblock then the button will appear inside it on the right side.When the mouse moves outside of the Business textblock then the button will disappear. If i click on the Business Textbox then a popup window will appear. The same thing for the button inside it. The popup window will show a list of value to let me choose.After clicking on one of those values & close the popup window, then the Business TextBox will show the value of the selected one from the popup window.

For implementation:

I am not sure whether it should be a Textblock which contains the Button with some conditioned animation to make the button appearing inside the textblock or not. However, I think that i should have made a rectangular shape then makes it become a button . Then puts a Textblock and Button inside the contentTemplate. The button only appears when the mouse moves over to the rectangular.

I don't really know how to make the animation work for the button when the mouse moves over to the rectangular and disappear when it gets out of it because this will involve both animation and controltemplate. Or whether my approach is correct or not

Any help will be appreciated

thank you

Comment: Can you take a screenshot exactly the control you want from the video and add it to your question? That video link/time position was not that helpful in figuring out exactly what you wanted. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were changing attributes of a single control I would say create a reusable *Behaviour* and attach that to the TextBlock control.

As you want to introduce an extra control, use a custom control in place of your TextBlock (not add a button to the TextBlock).

- Create a custom user control.
- Add a TextBlock and Button to it inside the standard LayoutRoot grid it creates.
- Edit the settings so that the button is initially hidden. *e.g. Opacity=0*
- Expose the TextBlock Text as a dependency property to allow normal binding to the content.
- Expose the button click as an event to allow outside users top catch the event
- Add ShowButton and HideButton storyboards to show and hide the button. Do this by altering the opacity value. If a button is completely transparent you cannot click it.

If you need specific help on how to do any of these steps, just ask. You can also contact us via our website.

*Note: Using Expression Blend for this type of work is 100 times easier than in VS 2010. Too many programmers ignore Blend as a design tool only. It is well worth the effort learning.

@Tai: As you asked nicely via email, here is a complete example of the sort of user control with dependency property for the text and event for the button. You can use this as a guide. I have stripped it down to the bare minimum:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.TextButtonControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="20" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ShowButtonStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ActionButton" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="HideShowButtonStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="ActionButton">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource HideShowButtonStoryboard}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource ShowButtonStoryboard}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <TextBlock x:Name="DisplayTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>

        <Button x:Name="ActionButton" Content="..." Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class TextButtonControl : UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs> ButtonClicked;

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(TextProperty, value);
                DisplayTextBlock.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text",
                                        typeof(string),
                                        typeof(TextButtonControl),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)));

        static void OnTextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            // If you need to know about text changes...
        }

        public TextButtonControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ActionButton.Click +=new RoutedEventHandler(ActionButton_Click);
        }

        private void ActionButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ButtonClicked != null)
            {
                ButtonClicked(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are so ROCK HiTechMagic. thank you a lot , this will be a good learning guide for me